# Connecting points by overlapping indices

Tags: python, pandas, object, tracking

I have a large list of arrays containing points with x and y coordinates. Each point also has it's own unique identifier. The arrays are arranged in a time sequence (each array is a single frame of a movie and the points represent "objects" in the movie). Some points appear on several frames, with slightly different coordinates. 
I used KDtrees to search for the nearest neighbor of each point in the previous and subsequent array (frame). Each point now has the identifier of its past and future neighbors attached to it. I store the points in a list of custom python objects, with all the necessary attributes (x, y, identifier, past neighbor ID, future neighbor ID.

I now need to connect these points into longer tracks, based on these overlapping past and future identifiers. Here's a graphical representation, in case I haven't made myself clear 
[image]

I tried using the following recursive function to do this:

```
def create_tracks(self):
    if self.track[-1].future_neighbor.ident is None:
        pass
    else:
        self.track.append(self.track[-1].future_neighbor)
        self.create_tracks()
```

Where future_neighbor is a point (stored as a custom object) and .ident is its unique identifier in the whole list of points. This works for shorter traces, but reaches the recursion limit for very long ones. I also have each point and its past and future neighbors stored in a pandas dataframe, if that makes it easier.

Another idea was to do something like this:

```
my_array = np.array([[np.nan,1,2],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]) #where each number is the unique ID of a point

#a seed is a point without a past neighbor -> start of a track
seeds_list = [i[1:].tolist() for i in my_array if np.isnan(i[0])]
for i in seeds_list:
    for p in my_array:
        if p[1] == i[-1]:
           i.append(p[2])
```

This also works, it iterates through every seed point, then iterates through the whole array of ALL points and appends their IDs to the ID of the seed point. However, since it's a for loop within a foor loop it takes ages for my large (several 100k points) datasets.

Is there a better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> my_array = np.array([[np.nan,1,2],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
>>> pd.Series(my_array.ravel()).drop_duplicates().values
array([nan,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work. The data I showed up there was just an example. There's a lot more in the array, I need to make many connections and some points are not connected to anything. I wish it were as simple as finding unique values, though.